# How do you use a generic type as return value and a generic type as a parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I try to create an abstract class with generics. The business logic is to translate a text from one language to another. There must be a `Translator` class for each language. I also require a `LanguageTranslation` class for each language, which is the return object of the `translate` method, which takes on the parameter `T`. That T is supposed to be of a sub class of `OriginalText` (e.g. EnglishText, ChineseText, etc). And that is where I struggle. How do you code this constraint?

I've created the following super class.

```
public abstract class Translator <T, V> {            
    public abstract <V extends LanguageTranslation> V translate(T originalText);
}
```

If I misunderstand the concept of generics or apply it wrong, please illuminate. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any class representing `OriginalText`? Or is that the name of the class only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it where you define your Generics :

```
public abstract class Translator <T extends OriginalText, V> {            
    public abstract <V extends LanguageTranslation> V translate(T originalText);
}
```

Btw, this is confusing because the `V` definition is overriden in your method. Why not doing this :

```
public abstract class Translator <T extends OriginalText, V extends LanguageTranslation> {            
    public abstract V translate(T originalText);
}
```

**EDIT: explaining why you have a warning on V**

It's exactly the same as :

```
public abstract class Translator <T extends OriginalText, V> {            
    public abstract <K extends LanguageTranslation> K translate(T originalText);
}
```

Now inside the method you have 3 generics :

- K of runtime determined subtype of LanguageTranslation
- T of runtime determined subtype of OriginalText
- V runtime determined subtype of Object (default constraint)

Comment: Fast, you are! I did not know one could specify this constraint in the class's head. Thanks, TecHunter.

Comment: if one also moves the extends of the return type to the class's head, you may even omit the warning `The type parameter V is hiding the type V`.

Comment: @feder the V parameter simply disappear from the method scope. see my edit