# How to extend the generic class properly?

Tags: java, generics

My question is a generic syntax question. As answered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027981/how-do-you-use-a-generic-type-as-return-value-and-a-generic-type-as-a-parameter/19028021?noredirect=1#comment28116252_19028021), I created the abstract generic super class.

```
public abstract class Translator <T extends OriginalText, V extends LanguageTranslation> {            
    public abstract V translate(T originalText);
}
```

Now, I fail in defining the child class.

```
public class ChineseToEnglishTranslator extends Translator<ChineseText, EnglishTranslation> {
    @Override
    public EnglishTranslation translate(ChineseText text) {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Eclipse returns the error: `Bound mismatch: The type ChineseText is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends OriginalText> of the type Translator<T,V>`. ChineseText is definitely a child class of OriginalText. What is the syntax of what I want to do?

Comment: `"ChineseText is definitely a child class of OriginalText"` - prove it. Show us the code. Better yet, give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I only get that error if `ChineseText` doesn't extend `OriginalText`.

Comment: @feder Post `OriginalText` if it's a generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `ChineseText extends OriginalText`.

**I'm not getting any errors as you have said** if `ChineseText extends OriginalText`.

> Bound mismatch: The type ChineseText is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter  of the type
>   Translator.

This error appears only when `ChineseText` doesn't extends `OriginalText`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ChineseText` is child of `OriginalText` and `EnglishTranslation` is child of `LanguageTranslation`, the `Translator` class that uses wildcard `extends` allows to all classes `<? extends OriginalText>` to use `Translator`. By the same way for `LanguageTranslation`

**EnglishTranslation**

```
public class EnglishTranslation extends LanguageTranslation{

}
```

**ChineseText**

```
public class ChineseText extends OriginalText{

}
```

**OriginalText**

```
public class OriginalText {

}
```

**LanguageTranslation**

```
public class LanguageTranslation {

}
```

**ChineseToEnglishTranslator**

```
public class ChineseToEnglishTranslator extends Translator<ChineseText, EnglishTranslation> {

@Override
public EnglishTranslation translate(ChineseText originalText) {
    return null;
}  
}
```

Comment: sorry mates! In my components I had the same (generated) classes. Once I referenced the one from lib A and the other time the one from lib B. A big sorry for that! These things usually don't happen to me.